# Suspend after screen lock in GNOME on Xorg

Tags: debian, gnome, xorg, gnome-shell, gdm

I'm using **GNOME 43.4** version on `Xorg`, along with `gdm3`.
GNU/Linux System Debian 12.

I want to disable the option for the system not to suspend when I lock the screen (Super+L).

By `gnome-tweaks` and ohter ways, it only works if I'm using GNOME over `Wayland`. Already, as I'm using `Xorg`, it keeps suspending.

I tried changing these options in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

`HandleLidSwitch=ignore HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore`

But even so, when blocking (Super+L) the system goes into sleep mode.

I also tried masking some services via `SystemD`:

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target suspend-then-hibernate.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

In addition, I also made some changes to `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`:

`AllowSuspend=no AllowHibernation=no AllowSuspendThenHibernate=no AllowHybridSleep=no`

But still it keeps turning off the screen and suspending the system.

I would like to understand why this keeps happening, and disable this suspend after lock screen.